# Kafka Manualy Remove Topic with Special Characters in Name

Tags: apache-kafka

Somehow managed to get a topic with a [ in the topic name. While trying to remove it, the shell errors out with invalid regex. How do I format the topic name so it will delete?

Command:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper $zkeeper --topic Test.Mapping.FlatFile.S[treaming
```

Error:

```
ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException: Test.Mapping.FlatFile.S[treaming is an invalid regex.
```

Comment: If you have only a single topic starting with Test.Mapping.FlatFile.S use regex (\*). 
./kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper $zkeeper --topic Test.Mapping.FlatFile.\* or you can try to escape the "[" in the name like "\\[" and try!

Comment: I missed the comment and posted the same as answer. I deleted my answer. Escaping is done by using \\ like Test.Mapping.FlatFile.S\\\[treaming

Comment: `delete.topic.enable` is this parameter enabled?

Comment: You could delete the data manually via Zookeeper shell + data directory on broker

Comment: @alili that did the trick, thank you.